# Perform RabbitMq through nginx

Tags: nginx, rabbitmq

I would like to perform actions through nginx.

Like :

```
MQ->addQueue("work","to do");
//This queue performs to nginx listener or connection
server {
    listen 5672; // or connect
    proxy_pass http://stream_workers
}
//Then 
Worker->on('work',httpData->{body:"to do"});
```

Basically convert job to http request.

My problem is I can't find any modules that connect nginx to rabbitmq for performing queues.

Comment: I am looking for something similar, have you find the answer to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`stream`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html) module  for this

```
stream {
  server {
    listen 5672;
    proxy_pass rabbitmq:5672;
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks like vice versa . I mean . how I set credentials there . Like nginx should some how connect to rabbitmq.

Comment: You can't do that with stream based backends. You will have to use lua + Nginx. https://github.com/wingify/lua-resty-rabbitmqstomp